# SignalR hub.On methods work after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, websocket, signalr

I have this code on ReactJS and SignalR. The SignalR On methods works only after page refresh. Please explain me how to solve this problem.

```
componentDidMount() {    
    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://test.com/hub', { accessTokenFactory: () => Cookies.get('access_token') })
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
      .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 0, 2000])
      .build();

    connection.on('MessageCount', () => someMethod());
    connection.on('Dialog', () => someMethod());
    connection.on('Send', () => someMethod());
    connection.start().then(() => console.log('Connected'));    
   
  }
```